# JavaFx import au Jpanel into Pane

Tags: swing, jpanel, javafx, awt, pane

i just started to learn java and i don't understand how to convert a JPanel to Pane.

I use Netbeans 1.4 and JavaFX scene builder 1.1.

Java Scene builder generate only a Pane and not a JPanel.

I tried to use Swing Node but i don't understand at all.

thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a Swing component, yes, you must do it by code without using Scene Builder.

You should take a look [here](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) it's the API documentation for SwingNode and has a nice example you could use.